# How to Ctrl+Shift+Space shortcut shows method help on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse, when mouse pointer moves over on method help hint shows. I want to show method help on eclipse like Visual Studio. When I pressed Ctrl+Shift+Space when cursor inside method parenthesis, I want to see method help as hint. How can I do it? Which shortcut's setting should I change?

[image]

PS: Netbeans IDE completley works as I wanted, but I want to do same in eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean the javadoc for the method?

Comment: I meant help hint. I want to see the help hint like mouse over on method name.

Comment: If I understands you correctly, then this is Ctrl-Space in Eclipse...

Comment: Ctrl+Space brings the overloaded functions. But I want to see the help of method. The help hint, when you moved your mouse over method name.

Comment: so you want to have the same behaviour as with the mouse over but with keys combination?

Comment: Mouse behavior can work at the same time. But I want to use keyboard too.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the JavaDoc View (`View -> Show View -> JavaDoc` / `Alt+Shift+Q,J`) to show the JavaDoc of the method your text cursor is inside. Or place the mouse cursor over the method name and the JavaDoc will be presented as tooltip.

`F2` (Show Tooltip decription) will give you the JavaDoc as mentioned in your question update. `Ctrl-Shift-Space` gives you Context Information (e.g. list of all possible methods) and you probably won't lose this due to new declaration.

Answer (score 3):

In General > Editors > Keys look the command should be "Show tooltip description", which is binded to F2 as default (same effect as the hover tooltip)

Comment: It works when keyboard cursor inside method name string but inside parenthesis.

Comment: @uzay95 - Well, the hover tooltip doesn't show up either when you place the mouse keyboard inside parenthesis.. What's wrong with `F2` on the method name and `Ctrl+Space` inside the parenthesis? :/ Not quick enough?

Answer (score 0):

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> General**

In the other Section you will find - "Show quick doc on mouse move"
Just mark the checkbox to help in 500ms(Time delay is changable)